# How to configure Monit for use with Puma Ruby Web Server?

Tags: ruby, monit

I am getting started with Monit and don't have a lot of systems knowledge. I have a Ruby app running on [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma). I want to use Monit to automatically restart Puma if it ever dies. I'm currently using the [Puma provided Capistrano 2 recipe](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/capistrano.rb) which uses the control script instead of outputting the PID to a file.

Is there a way to configure monit to check the status of Puma to see if it should be restarted?

Answer (score 2):

This is for Capistrano 3.

You can use the "official" Capistrano recipe for Puma. https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma

It has monit scripts built-in to monitor puma server processes. Just include `require 'capistrano/puma/monit'` in your `Capfile`. And run `cap <stage> puma:monit:config` . That's it.